# How to receive broadcast when phone locked?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a notification to broadcast a custom intent filter when clicked on.

If the phone is locked the broadcast is not received until it's unlocked. Is there anyway to change it so it's received even when locked?

Comment: What does this mean ? `I have a notification to broadcast a custom intent filter when clicked on`> Explain pls.

Comment: @ADM A foreground service is running a notification 24/7. When clicked it broadcasts an intent to a receiver I created. The broadcast is received but only when the phone is unlocked.